# Spin FontAwesome Icon on hover in Angular

Tags: css, font-awesome

I know there are many examples how to spin a icon with CSS and stuff but somehow I can't achieve what I want.

```
<button id="button" mat-button type="button" class="fa-spin-hover" (click)="doSomething()">
  <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'sync']" [spin]="false" size="lg" class="rotate">
  </fa-icon>
</button>
```

I don't know what's the best practice here. Of course I could create a boolean value and do something like `[spin]="bool"` but I don't think thats the right way. If I use `class="fa-spin-hover"` on the button the whole button spins but it works. If I use it on `<fa-icon>` it does not work.

```
.fa-spin-hover:hover {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s 1 linear;
  -moz-animation: fa-spin 2s 1 linear;
  -o-animation: fa-spin 2s 1 linear;
  animation: fa-spin 2s 1 linear;
}
```

I tried several things. Thats also why the attribute `class="rotate"` is on `<fa-icon>`. I tried to only have a 180 degree spin on hovering:

```
.rotate:hover {
  animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out 0s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

But these classes are useless on `<fa-icon>`. Also tried things like `::ng-deep`

Created a StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-font-awesome-starter-msp1vu

Comment: Can you demo this? It might be as simple as giving the icon `display:inline-block` and then putting the class on the icon, not the button.

Comment: @Paulie_D stackblitz added

Comment: @Paulie_D ???? what are you talking about. And your idea does not work.

Comment: So no idea? I thought it's my fault...